# KCFinder dont show correctly

Tags: php, ckeditor, kohana, kohana-3.3

I'm searching all over for solution for my problem and cant find anything that work.

The problem:
I work with KOHANA framework and try to integrate KCFinder with my CKEditor.
At first it didnt work because some routing problems.
after going through almost all the files in kcfinder to replace all "require" and all the functions that need to call other files to the correct route.
finally the kcfinder window load with all the files.

but now i got another problem,
now the window look like

[image: KCFinder Window]

Here is the console for this page:

[image: KCFinder Console]

does anyone have any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you show joiner.php and browse.php in the relevant parts?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an HTML problem ... so basically do a view source and find the missing CSS file and make sure the HTML that gets pumped out is pulling the CSS file properly ... nothing to do with PHP or Kohana at all

Answer (score 0):

this is my browse.php

```
$base = APPPATH.'includes/kcfinder/';
require $base.'core/uploader.php';
require $base.'core/browser.php';
require $base.'core/autoload.php';
require $base.'core/types/type_img.php';
require $base.'core/types/type_mime.php';
require $base.'lib/class_gd.php';
require $base.'lib/class_input.php';
require $base.'lib/class_zipFolder.php';
require $base.'lib/helper_dir.php';
require $base.'lib/helper_file.php';
require $base.'lib/helper_httpCache.php';
require $base.'lib/helper_path.php';
require $base.'lib/helper_text.php';
$browser = new browser();
$browser->action();
```

and this is my joiner.php

```
$base = APPPATH.'includes/kcfinder/';
require $base.'core/uploader.php';
require $base.'core/browser.php';
require $base.'core/autoload.php';

require $base.'core/types/type_img.php';
require $base.'core/types/type_mime.php';

require $base.'lib/class_gd.php';
require $base.'lib/class_input.php';
require $base.'lib/class_zipFolder.php';
require $base.'lib/helper_dir.php';
require $base.'lib/helper_file.php';
require $base.'lib/helper_httpCache.php';
require $base.'lib/helper_path.php';
require $base.'lib/helper_text.php';
$files = glob(dirname(__FILE__).'/*.js');
sort($files);
```

....